# How to use Extract<T, U> with nested variant?

Tags: typescript

I'm running into an issue with generated types. An API is giving me one of two types, and I wish to alias them individually.

TypeScript has `Extract<>` to help with this:

```
type Add = {
    type: 'add';
    id: string;
}
  
type Remove = {
    type: 'remove';
    id: string;
}
  
type Action = Add | Remove;

type addType = Extract<Action, {type: 'add'}>;
    // ^? Add
```

However, my variants are described differently:

```
type ActionsCombined = {
    type: 'add' | 'remove';
    id: string;
}

type addTypeCombined = Extract<ActionsCombined, {type: 'add'}>;
    // ^? never
```

The two seem equivalent to me, and yet TypeScript doesn't see that they are. Is there a way to extract the `add` variant from `ActionsCombined`?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=17&pln=3&pc=16#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnKBeKBvAUFLVSQFxQDkAhgoQNybYCWcBAzsAE7UB2A5pQL5Xq7QAlCAFsA9gDdoKDNhzgIBQkxESIFKlloNmbTuh5Y+82AGNg1Ua2SwEUAD5QhYyZSOQopOABVjKAKIAHszEZgA8MGYWrAA0aPyKnoRcAHyUsgD06VAAegD86AX8puaW9ADCosIARmwQiNIacvhEifZEys5qaTR0UIwsHNyFxp4+kBXVtfVQgcFhESWs5ZU1rHWxqPEtZCndWJk5uUA)

Alternatively, is it possible to turn the nested variant representation into two unrelated variants?

Comment: You are narrowing the type, so you need `type addTypeCombined = ActionsCombined & { type: 'add' };`

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to convert the combined actions type into a generic:

```js
type CombinedActions<T extends 'add' | 'remove'> = {
    type: T;
    id: string;
}

type BlankAction = CombinedActions; // ERROR: Generic type 'CombinedActions' requires 1 type argument(s)
type AddAction = CombinedActions<'add'>; // type AddAction = { type: "add"; id: string; }
type RemoveAction = CombinedActions<'remove'>; // type AddAction = { type: "remove"; id: string; }
type TypoRemoveAction = CombinedActions<'remive'>; // ERROR: Type '"remive"' does not satisfy the constraint '"add" | "remove"'.
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwEYEsB2EAmBBAxsFONAZwB4AVKCAD2AjU2KgHIBDTTZqAHxYCcICOADcIzAHxQAvFADeAKChKooSAC4o5ANyLlKTBuLA+6AOY6AvvPmroAIQA2rNAGs8BItNiJUGHPkISHVsobA53QK94ZHQsCKIyNg4JYPBoACVBEQh4tCifWP8PElJmASFRFJs0zXA4TIqcgM8ZaN845pKywRRK8R0gA)

Comment: This doesn't work as my `CombinedActions` type is generated.

Comment: ...generated from where? Does it come with a library or something? Can you modify the "generated type" (as you said) like above?